# Наследование перегрузки операторов

Tags: c#

Есть класс `Tree`, у него есть свойство `Mass`.

```
class Tree
{
  public decimal Mass {get; set;}
}
```

Есть класс `Apple`, наследуемый от `Tree`

```
class Apple : Tree
{
}
```

Добавляю в класс `Tree` перегрузку оператора `+`

```
public static Tree operator +(Tree tree1, Tree tree2)
{
    Tree result = new Tree();
    result.Mass = tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass;
    return result;
}
```

Какого типа будет объект `apple3` в следующем фрагменте?

```
Apple apple1 = new Apple {Mass = 20};
Apple apple2 = new Apple {Mass = 30};
var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
```

Предполагаю, что типа `Tree`. А как сделать, чтобы реализация перегрузки осталась в `Tree`, а в результате получать `Apple`? Цель - не писать реализацию для каждого наследника `Tree`.

Comment: У Вас действия в `operator+` исключительно над полями `Tree`, т.е. непонятно о какой реализации в наследниках может быть речь.

Comment: @alexolut, 1) свойство `Mass` public и будет доступно наследникам 2) но рассуждать о реализации в наследниках смысла нет, т.к. вопрос о реализации в предке

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/561977/Генерация-объектов-наследников-в-коде-предка-и-производительность

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этой ситуации хорошо подойдёт [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>, new()
{
    public decimal Mass { get; set; }

    public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)
    {
        var result = new TChild();
        result.Mass = tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass;
        return result;
    }
}

class Apple : Tree<Apple>
{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Apple apple1 = new Apple { Mass = 20 };
    Apple apple2 = new Apple { Mass = 30 };
    Apple apple3 = apple1 + apple2; // можно присвоить результат сложения в переменную типа Apple
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите насколько обязательно в данном примере использование ограничения `new()`

Comment: Да, так как без ограничения нельзя вызывать new TChild в статическом методе (т.е. нельзя создавать инстанс типа TChild без явного ограничения new() )

Comment: При вызове `new TChild()` возможна просадка производительности. Я бы не стал так делать.

Comment: @3per без ограничения `new()` придётся выдумывать другой способ генерации этих `TChild`ов — сходу какого-то общего решения мне не видится. Замечание товарища @PavelMayorov по поводу производительности верно — в таких случаях компилятор создаёт объекты дочернего класса через `Activator`, то есть не самым быстрым способом (если я не путаю ничего).

Comment: @PavelMayorov, предложите Ваш вариант, интересно было бы посмотреть.

Comment: @isnullxbh вопрос не про замену `new()` - потому развернуто ответить не могу. Варианта тут два: либо создание экземпляра через `Expressions`, либо защищенный абстрактный метод для создания нового экземпляра.

Comment: Если не хочется создавать новый объект при сложении, то не стоит делать оператор. Тогда нужен метод вида `Tree.Add(Tree tree)`. Вообще, перегрузка операторов бывает крайне редко нужна, и использовать её без реальной необходимости не стоит.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, "развернуто ответить не могу" создал отдельный вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561977/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Ещё один недостаток подхода - я теперь не могу создать `List<Tree<TChild>>` в других классах

Comment: @3per можно, если указывать констрейнт. Например: `class Foo<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>, new() { List<Tree<TChild>> x; }` должно работать.