# Генерация объектов наследников в коде предка и производительность

Tags: c#

В предыдущем вопросе [Наследование перегрузки операторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561690/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/561698#561698), подсказали что нужно сделать, чтобы предок мог возвращать экземпляры класса наследника.

```
class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>, new()
{
    public decimal Mass { get; set; }

    public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)
    {
        var result = new TChild();
        result.Mass = tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass;
        return result;
    }
}

class Apple : Tree<Apple>
{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Apple apple1 = new Apple { Mass = 20 };
    Apple apple2 = new Apple { Mass = 30 };
    Apple apple3 = apple1 + apple2; // можно присвоить результат сложения в переменную типа Apple
}
```

Но было отмечено, что `new TChild()` узкое место по производительности. Почему? Какие есть варианты для оптимальной производительности при генерации в коде предка экземпляров наследника?

Comment: Хм. Сама идея создания потомка в коде предка кажется мне сомнительной. (Да и CRTP до кучи тоже.)

Comment: @VladD, неужели дублирование кода в потомках лучше? Правда, есть еще вариант с приведением результата к типу потомка.

Comment: В зависимости от того, какова ваша _настоящая_ задача. Расскажите, для чего вам реально такая странная структура классов. Например, может быть вам вовсе не нужно наследование, раз у вас не добавляются данные и не появляются новые конструкторы?

Comment: @VladD, в настоящей задаче у меня базовый класс "физическая величина", а наследники "масса", "время", "температура", "объем", "давление" и т.д.. У базового есть св-во "Value" и его я хочу, складывать, вычитать, умножать и делить, получая в результате экземпляры наследников. У наследников, разумеется, есть свои уникальные методы и св-ва, насчет уникальных полей не уверен.

Comment: Когда мне нужно было делать похожую штуку, я делал операции индивидуально. Дело в том, что не все операции имеют физический смысл. Например, складывать два момента времени бессмысленно. А можно складывать момент времени и продолжительность, и получать момент времени. Складывать точки нельзя, но можно складывать вектора (и получать вектор), а также точку и вектор (и получать точку). И т. д.

Comment: Так что да, я бы посоветовал определять операции поштучно.

Comment: Кстати, в F# ваша задача (частично) решается «из коробки»: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewkennedy/2008/08/29/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units/ (по крайней мере, там есть встроенный [анализ размерности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)).

Answer (score 4):

Производительность плохая, потому что `new TChild()` превращается в вызов конструктора через reflection.

Как возможная альтернатива, можно сделать виртуальный метод `protected virtual Tree<TChild> CreateFromMass(decimal mass)`, который будет конструировать объект. В классе-наследнике его можно перегрузить, чтобы конструировался объект правильного типа.

Comment: попробовал. Наверно нужен `protected virtual TChild CreateFromMass(decimal mass)`

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле проблема с производительностью есть, но не такая уж и критичная. Около двух  раз медленнее с `Activator`-ом чем без. Для `double` замедление около четырых раз.

```
|                           Method |      Mean |    Error |    StdDev |    Median |
|--------------------------------- |----------:|---------:|----------:|----------:|
|       TestActivatorWithoutRandom |  92.93 ns | 2.335 ns |  6.738 ns |  89.96 ns |
|         TestVirtualWithoutRandom |  48.78 ns | 1.006 ns |  2.804 ns |  47.55 ns |
|        TestAbstractWithoutRandom |  46.79 ns | 1.058 ns |  3.086 ns |  45.54 ns |
| TestActivatorDoubleWithoutRandom |  71.79 ns | 2.363 ns |  6.929 ns |  67.73 ns |
|   TestVirtualDoubleWithoutRandom |  16.92 ns | 0.448 ns |  1.320 ns |  16.24 ns |
|  TestAbstractDoubleWithoutRandom |  17.14 ns | 0.492 ns |  1.444 ns |  16.49 ns |
|                    TestActivator | 114.69 ns | 3.711 ns | 10.588 ns | 110.46 ns |
|                      TestVirtual |  60.24 ns | 1.418 ns |  4.182 ns |  58.07 ns |
|                     TestAbstract |  60.15 ns | 1.338 ns |  3.923 ns |  58.04 ns |
|              TestActivatorDouble |  96.31 ns | 2.420 ns |  7.020 ns |  93.79 ns |
|                TestVirtualDouble |  41.92 ns | 1.002 ns |  2.953 ns |  40.92 ns |
|               TestAbstractDouble |  43.17 ns | 1.085 ns |  3.149 ns |  42.17 ns |
```

---

```
public class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WindowWidth = 120;
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<AppleTest>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }        
}

[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp21)]
[RPlotExporter]
public class AppleTest
{
    static Random Random = new Random();
    static long x = 0;
    static long y = 1_999;

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal TestActivatorWithoutRandom()
    {
        var apple1 = new Activator.Apple { Mass = x++ };
        var apple2 = new Activator.Apple { Mass = y-- };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal TestVirtualWithoutRandom()
    {
        var apple1 = new Virtual.Apple { Mass = x++ };
        var apple2 = new Virtual.Apple { Mass = y-- };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal TestAbstractWithoutRandom()
    {
        var apple1 = new Abstract.Apple { Mass = x++ };
        var apple2 = new Abstract.Apple { Mass = y-- };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double TestActivatorDoubleWithoutRandom()
    {
        var apple1 = new ActivatorDouble.Apple { Mass = x++ };
        var apple2 = new ActivatorDouble.Apple { Mass = y-- };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double TestVirtualDoubleWithoutRandom()
    {
        var apple1 = new VirtualDouble.Apple { Mass = x++ };
        var apple2 = new VirtualDouble.Apple { Mass = y-- };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double TestAbstractDoubleWithoutRandom()
    {
        var apple1 = new AbstractDouble.Apple { Mass = x++ };
        var apple2 = new AbstractDouble.Apple { Mass = y-- };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal TestActivator()
    {
        var apple1 = new Activator.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple2 = new Activator.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal TestVirtual()
    {
        var apple1 = new Virtual.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple2 = new Virtual.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal TestAbstract()
    {
        var apple1 = new Abstract.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple2 = new Abstract.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double TestActivatorDouble()
    {
        var apple1 = new ActivatorDouble.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple2 = new ActivatorDouble.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double TestVirtualDouble()
    {
        var apple1 = new VirtualDouble.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple2 = new VirtualDouble.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double TestAbstractDouble()
    {
        var apple1 = new AbstractDouble.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple2 = new AbstractDouble.Apple { Mass = Random.Next(int.MaxValue) };
        var apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
        return apple3.Mass;
    }
}

namespace Activator
{
    class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>, new()
    {
        public decimal Mass { get; set; }
        public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)
            => new TChild() { Mass = tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass };                
    }
    class Apple : Tree<Apple>{}
}

namespace Virtual
{
    class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>, new()
    {
        public decimal Mass { get; set; }
        public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)
            => tree1.CreateFromMass(tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass);

        protected virtual TChild CreateFromMass(decimal mass)
            => new TChild() { Mass = mass };
    }

    class Apple : Tree<Apple>
    {
        protected override Apple CreateFromMass(decimal mass)
            => new Apple { Mass = mass };
    }
}

namespace Abstract
{
    abstract class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>
    {
        public decimal Mass { get; set; }
        public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)            
            => tree1.CreateFromMass(tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass);
        protected abstract TChild CreateFromMass(decimal mass);
    }

    class Apple : Tree<Apple>
    {
        protected override Apple CreateFromMass(decimal mass)
            => new Apple { Mass = mass };            
    }
}

namespace ActivatorDouble
{
    class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>, new()
    {
        public double Mass { get; set; }
        public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)
            => new TChild() { Mass = tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass };
    }
    class Apple : Tree<Apple> { }
}

namespace VirtualDouble
{
    class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>, new()
    {
        public double Mass { get; set; }
        public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)
            => tree1.CreateFromMass(tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass);

        protected virtual TChild CreateFromMass(double mass)
            => new TChild() { Mass = mass };
    }

    class Apple : Tree<Apple>
    {
        protected override Apple CreateFromMass(double mass)
            => new Apple { Mass = mass };
    }
}

namespace AbstractDouble
{
    abstract class Tree<TChild> where TChild : Tree<TChild>
    {
        public double Mass { get; set; }
        public static TChild operator +(Tree<TChild> tree1, Tree<TChild> tree2)
            => tree1.CreateFromMass(tree1.Mass + tree2.Mass);
        protected abstract TChild CreateFromMass(double mass);
    }

    class Apple : Tree<Apple>
    {
        protected override Apple CreateFromMass(double mass)
            => new Apple { Mass = mass };
    }
}
```