# Повторная инициализация переменной

Tags: c#

Имеется класс `FormPar`, который наследуется от `Form`. Все остальные формы в проекте наследуются от `FormPar` и имеют общий стиль, а также некоторые элементы. В `FormPar` хранится ссылка на форму, из которой была вызвана данная форма: `Form previousF;`.

Как повторно инициализировать `previousF`, не зная ее типа? `switch` не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
previousF = (FormPar)Activator.CreateInstance(previousF.GetType());
```

Comment: По моему это не очень хороший совет. Во первых непонятно зачем создавать новый экземпляр формы, если уже есть созданный ранее экземпляр (в вопросе ТС по этому поводу нет разъяснений, а значит возможна неправильная трактовка вопроса). Во вторых, если уж на то пошло и надо заменить старый экземпляр новым, то у старого следует вызвать метод Dispose. Это необходимо, потому что класс Form отвечает за вызов Dispose всех своих компонентов. Например, если какой-нибудь компонент подписан на статическое событие, то отсутствие вызова Dispose приведет к утечке памяти.

Comment: @Uranus, ну кто создал экземпляр тот и должен уничтожить, а тут была задача переинициализоровать ссылочную переменную.

Comment: @Uranus Проблема заключалась в том, что Dispose уже был вызван и мне нужно было создать новый экземпляр формы, но я не знал способа решения возникшей проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

По моему мнению, более правильное решение - действовать через дженерики, например, так:

```
class FormPar<T> : Form where T : Form, new()
{
    T previousF;

    ...
}
```

Тогда создание нового экземпляра выглядит просто:

```
previousF = new T();
```

Comment: " а не через рефлексию" а `new T()` не через рефлексию работает? Ну оптимизировать инициализацию формы, может и нет смысла?

Comment: Нет, конечно, ведь при создании экземпляра будет подставлен конкретный тип: `new FormPar<MyForm33>()`, потом в `new T()` компилятор вызовет конструктор этого конкретного типа без использования рефлексии

Comment: А такой вызов имеет несколько преимуществ, в первую очередь - безопасность типов, ну и гарантию наличия конструктора без параметров, @4per

Comment: вот тут мне озвучивали другое мнение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561690/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment730783_561698

Comment: и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562078/22836

Comment: @4per, хм, ок, пусть не будет выигрыша производительности (убрал из ответа), но безопасность типов тоже важна, поэтому я всё же предлагаю использовать дженерики

Answer (score 2):

Вы не должны повторно инициализировать форму, повторное использование объектов — неправильно. Просто реализуйте интерфейс, в котором будет метод, создающий «свежую» форму, и пусть форма сама его и реализует.