# Перегрузка оператора при наследовании

Tags: c#, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

Можно как-нибудь наследовать перегрузку операторов? Сейчас я повторно дублирую код, например как в нижеприведенном коде.

**Базовый класс**

```
using System;
namespace Test
{

public class Base
{
    public double Num { get; set; }

    public Base()
    {

    }

    public Base(Base num)
    {
        Num = num.Num;
    }


    // Перегрузим арифметические операции в базовом классе
    public static Base operator +(Base x, Base y)
    {
        Base base = new Base();
        return new Base(base.Addition(x, y));
    }


    // Какая-то реализация (для перегрузки в базовом классе)
    public virtual Base Addition(Base x, Base y)
    {
        Base base = new Base();
        base.Num = ((x.Num + y.Num) + 10) / 2;

        return base;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format($"{Num} ");
    }
  }
}
```

**Производный класс**

```
namespace Test
{

public class RealNumber : Base
{
    public RealNumber()
    {

    }


    public RealNumber(RealNumber num)
    {
        Num = num.Num;
    }

    // Какая-то реализация (для перегрузки в производном классе)
    public RealNumber Addition(RealNumber x, RealNumber y)
    {
        RealNumber realNumber = new RealNumber();
        realNumber.Num = x.Num + y.Num;

        return realNumber;
    }


    public static RealNumber operator +(RealNumber x, RealNumber y)
    {
        RealNumber realNumber = new RealNumber();
        return new RealNumber(realNumber.Addition(x, y));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте дописать `virtual`, если это не поможет (недопустимо) - то прийдется из статики вызывать динамическую ф-цию, и ф-цию делать `virtual`

Comment: технически наверное можно сделать что-то типа `virtual MyType Add(MyType b)` и вызывать ее в статике, но вызов все равно придется дублировать от класса к классу. Либо определять статику в абстрактном общем предке, но это тоже узкоспециализированная штука получится, в общем случае не пригодна.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561690/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: @rdorn ^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 4):

В простом явном виде нельзя.

Оператор определяется в статическом методе. Формально, по спецификации, они наследуются, но есть существенная разница в действующих механизмах наследования статических членов и членов экземпляра. По факту все наследование статических методов сводится к неограниченному доступу к данным методам через производные классы, но ни каких бонусов в виде адаптации сигнатуры под производный класс или возможности сделать метод виртуальным нет.

Есть обходные пути, для решения проблемы, один из них в соседнем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Наследование перегрузки операторов происходит само собой. Но все типы в сигнатуре останутся, как в предке. То есть при сложении двух RealNumber вы получите объект Base. Как с этим бороться описано здесь [Наследование перегрузки операторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561690)

А в следующем вопросе на эту тему ([Генерация объектов наследников в коде предка и производительность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561977)) мне предложили отказаться от этой идеи. И в конечном итоге я выбрал этот вариант.

Comment: Видел, и даже отметился там в свое время. Но это решение все таки не является наследованием, что противоречит исходному вопросу. Согласно спецификации операторы как и любые статические методы не наследуются. А обходные маневры есть, каждый со своими тараканами и областью применимости. Минусовать не буду, но и корректным решением не считаю.

Comment: @rdorn, Во дела.. я правда думал что наследуются. По поведению-то не отличишь. Пошел читать пруфы..

Comment: @rdorn `Как и другие члены, операторы, объявленные в базовом классе, наследуются производными классами.` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#operators

Comment: мдя... че то это совсем грибами отдает. Спорить со спеками не буду, раз уж написали, но спеки пытаются спорить со здравым смыслом и концепциями ООП. Статика всегда была вне объектной модели, в том смысле что не привязана к объектам, следовательно и наследоваться не может, иначе почему отсутствует наследование у статических классов? Похоже такие же грибы как с наследованием у интерфейсов, которое ни разу не наследование, но объявляется одинаково - значит наследование... Мне категорически не понятно зачем называть одним и тем же термином разные по сути вещи. Не этого я ждал от 21-го века =(

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `virtual` методы. Я покажу на примере с `IEquitable<T>`

```
class Base : IEquitable<Base>
{
    public static readonly Base Default = new Base();

    public int BaseValue { get; }

    public Base(int value)
    {
        BaseValue = value;
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(Base? comparand) =>
        BaseValue == (comparand ?? Default).BaseValue;

    public static bool operator ==(Base? a, Base? b) =>
        a is null ? (b is null ? true : b.Equals(a)) : // у нас `null == Default` b `Default == null`
            a.Equals(b);
    public static bool operator !=(Base? a, Base? b) => !(a == b);
}
```

```
class Derived : Base, IEquitable<Derived>
{
    public new static readonly Derived Default = new Derived();

    public int DerivedValue { get; }

    public Derived(int baseValue, int value) : base(baseValue)
    {
        DerivedValue = value;
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(Derived? comparand) =>
        DerivedValue == (comparand ?? Default).DerivedValue &&
        base.Equals(comparand); // implicit case `Derived` -> `Base`
    public override bool Equals(Base? comparand) =>
        comparand is Derived derived ? Equals(derived) :
            base.Equals(comparand); // or `false`

    public static bool operator ==(Derived? a, Derived? b) =>
        a is null ? (b is null ? true : b.Equals(a)) : a.Equals(b);
    public static bool operator !=(Derived? a, Derived? b) => !(a == b);
}
```