# Наследование обобщенного класса такого же типа как у "наследника", С#

Tags: c#, наследование

Нужен ответ на вопрос почему корректен следующий код и привести пример кода:

```
class A <T>{}
 class B: A<B>{}
//тут ошибка VS намекает на - циклическую зависимость
//class c: c {}
```

Ответ: Это типичная реализация CRTP техники.

Comment: какой полный текст ошибки? на какую именно строчку ругается? какая версия студии?

Comment: А как ты себе представляешь наследование от самого себя?

Comment: Нужен ответ на вопрос, почему две первые строчки корректны. Ошибку привел для общей картины.

Comment: _почему две первые строчки корректны_ - потому что это корректное наследование.

Comment: а где(для чего) такое может применяться? для понимание

Comment: так сразу не могу придумать, видел только в виде реализации singleton, когда статическое поле было в базовом классе и специфицировалось за счет наследования

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а где там?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity посмотрите

Comment: @Grundy перепутал немного...

Comment: @Kans, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561690/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это типичная реализация CRTP техники, пришедшей из C++. Почему это корректно? А почему, собственно, нет? Ведь мы не создаём никаких циклических зависимостей, мы просто в качестве обобщённого параметра указываем сами себя. Но, заметьте, мы указываем сами себя не себе, а другому классу, пусть и родителю. Не скажу, что знаю как это применяется в C#, но в C++ это очень распространённая практика. Если интересно, можете почитать мою статью по [CRTP в C++](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/26/crtp_demystified.aspx), а также я нашёл небольшую статью по [применению CRTP в C#](https://habrahabr.ru/post/211743/) на Хабрахабр.

Comment: Для равновесия, вот статья Эрика _против_ CRTP: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/